# PowerShell NamedPipe the Encoding of the StreamReader of the pipe?

Tags: powershell, named-pipes

sorry for being nasty with that stupid pipe - but I need it :(

I defined the pipe and it´s reader:

```
 $Enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII # UTF8 #  
 $Buf = new-object byte[] 4096
 $pipeDir  = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut
 $pipeMsg  = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode]::Byte  
 $pipeOpti = [System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions]::Asynchronous 
 $pipe = New-Object system.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream(` 
                $pipeName, $pipeDir, 1, $pipeMsg, $pipeOpti )
 $pr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $pipe $Enc $false 4096 $true
 $pr
```

and I get the error

```
 No Position-Parameter found that would accept "System.Text.ASCIIEncoding" at ..
 + $pr = new-object <<<<  System.IO.StreamReader $pipe $Enc $false 4096 $true
       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], 
                                 ParameterBindingException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,
                                 Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

 CurrentEncoding : System.Text.UTF8Encoding
 BaseStream      : System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream
 EndOfStream     : True
```

But I would prefer (need?) ASCII:
What can do??

If I define the Reader just like that (otherwise it doesn't read anything):

```
 $pr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $pipe
```

I get at the read function

```
 readReader $pr, $Buff, $Enc
 ...
 #(in that function:)
 try {
      $read = $r.Read($b, 0, $b.Length)
        if ($read -ne 0) { Write-Host "READ: $read  $($b[0..$($read-1)])" }
        if($read -gt 0) {
                 $foundmore = $true
                 $got += $e.GetString($b, 0, $read)
                 $nTry = -1
                 Write-Host "rdMsg: rd:$read, $got" 
        }
 } catch { $foundMore = $false; $read = 0; }
```

I can read this output:

```
  READ: 4  0 0 0 0
  rdMsg: rd:4,     
  READ: 27  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  rdMsg: rd:27,
```

Finally the script hangs at read:

```
     $read = $r.Read($b, 0, $b.Length)
```

until the pipe was closed from the other side

Where aer my mistakes? - Please
Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$pr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $pipe $Enc $false 4096 $true
```

should be written:

```
$pr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($pipe, $Enc, $false, 4096, $true)
```

Comment: I have tried that and failed and I got/get the same error: No Overloading for "Streamreader" and the following number of arguments could have been found (my translation from German)